# Hamburger menu with HTML, CSS and JavaScript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting a text cursor when I click the hamburger menu. As shown in the below image:

[image]

The following is the HTML for the hamburger menu:

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--clr-black);
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .animation.bar1 {
    transform: translate(0, 7.1px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .animation.bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .animation.bar3 {
    transform: translate(0, -7.1px) rotate(45deg);
  }
</style>
```

```
<script>
 document.querySelector('.bar1').classList.toggle('animation')
 document.querySelector('.bar2').classList.toggle('animation')
document.querySelector('.bar3').classList.toggle('animation')
</script>`
```

I tried the above codes. The hamburger menu is working. But when I click it a text cursor appears at the (bottom) hamburger menu.

I want to remove that cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like the below snippet. I simplified your code a little bit down the route. Also, later for accessibility, I would suggest you use a `button` for `hamburger-menu` instead of a `div`.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("animation");
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.animation .bar1 {
  transform: translate(0, 7.1px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.animation .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animation .bar3 {
  transform: translate(0, -7.1px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <div class="bar bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar bar3"></div>
</div>
```